# WPF charting/visualization of realtime data

Tags: wpf, graphics, real-time, charts, data-visualization

I've been trying to figure out what is the appropriate way to render real-time data as a line graph in WPF. And by real-time I actually mean, data that is being collected from a USB device that generates data at a rate of approximately 40Hz. There are multiple (up to 7) streams of data that I'm reading at 40Hz in an asynchronous fashion.

I've tried using two off-the shelf solutions (WPF Toolkit charting and Swordfish charts) and almost looked into the Dynamic Data Visualization component but gave up on it after reading some comments on their forum. It seems that off-the-shelf charting solutions are geared towards static charts and I actually need something similar to the Windows Task Manager - only much faster and with way more data points.

Currently, I've rolled my own solution which seems to work the best so far but I have a feeling that I'm missing something because it seems that I should be able to get better performance out of it.

The requirements are that it should be able to handle a constant range of about 10000 points in a sliding window - as new data comes in (at 40Hz), old data get's pushed to the left outside of the visible range. And it needs to sustain this rate for at least 20 - 30 minutes (a total of about 75 - 100 thousand points per data stream).

My current custom implementation is a based on a component that inherits from Shape and uses a StreamingGeometry for the DefinigGeometry. The data coming in from the device is passed to the component via a queue to improve performance due to the inherent "bursting effect" and after a dequeue operation, the component is invalidated.

So, my question is, am I on the right path or am I completely wrong? What is the most efficient way to accomplish such data visualization in WPF? Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: DirectX interop is the direction.  Some will use slimDX but it's a huge dependency and abstract learning curve. I recommend direct use of DX9 or (DX11 via DXGI) as it hand shakes with the WPF D3DImage interface. Still a learning curve but same as slimdx and more maintainable to create a DX device, context, buffer, shader and get your app using Direct3D. Docs are terrible but good enough, and when done, you've accomplished something cool with no dependency on others. See our real world [18M charting demo](http://www.gigasoft.com) with WPF WinForm MFC EXEs, its mostly audio WAV and GIS data.

Comment: @Robert, thanks for the input. Ideally I'd like to stick w DX9 to be compatible w XP but so for I couldn't figure out no to draw arbitrarily thick lines with D3D in a way that's comparable in quality to the aliased paths that I achieved with WPF. Any pointers? Did you have to write your own tesselation routine? I would even be ok with DX10 if I can get what I want performance/quality wise.

Comment: Thick lines is the largest drawback with D3D. Though its not a big deal. If you can design around a known chart size, then the vertex buffer logic will know a size and its a simple matter of drawing the line as quads (double triangles) b) if you don't want to rebuild your vertex buffer based on a size event, then the shader should be designed to hold an aspect ratio and physical size settings in a constant buffer, then this data used within the vertex shader to tweak your line quads on the fly.  This is the case for dx9/11. Or you can use D2D and data reduction logic to plot large quantities.

Comment: And to add, the beauty of Win7 Win8 is compositing D2D and D3D. So when you need a high-level graphics like a thick line, or simplified text, etc, and don't need a ton of it, you can combine D2D and D3D in the same rendering with little seen performance hit. Our demo does this with the 12M data point audio data wav example 123 and the thick vertical line annotation showing play position in both main chart and zoom-window.  Same goes for thicker lines in the grid and such.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned before, the WPF "standard" way of doing this will not get you the required performance. After trying several different free and commercial products and not getting what I needed, I started to experiment with the following methods:

1. Using WPF geometry.
2. Using Direct2D.

Both of them were not performant at all.

One thing I know is that WPF is good at rendering images (BitmapSource), so I decided to go to that direction and use WriteableBitmapEx to draw the graph on a WriteableBitmap then pass it on...

One problem with the WriteableBitmapEx library is that it doesn't have much drawing features like, for instance GDI. So why not just use GDI? there is no difference if you do it right.

Example:

```cs
    public void BeginDraw()
    {
        _writeable_bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)Math.Max(_size.Width, 1), 
        (int)Math.Max(_size.Height, 1), 96.0, 96.0, PixelFormats.Pbgra32, null);

        _gdi_bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(_writeable_bitmap.PixelWidth, 
        _writeable_bitmap.PixelHeight,_writeable_bitmap.BackBufferStride,
        System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb,
        _writeable_bitmap.BackBuffer);

        _writeable_bitmap.Lock();

        _g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(_gdi_bitmap);
        _g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        _g.Clear(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
    }

    public void DrawSeries(IEnumerable<System.Drawing.PointF> points)
    {
        _g.DrawCurve(dataSeries.GdiPen, points.ToArray());
    }

    public void EndDraw()
    {
        _writeable_bitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, 
        _writeable_bitmap.PixelWidth, _writeable_bitmap.PixelHeight));
        _writeable_bitmap.Unlock();

        var cloned = _writeable_bitmap.Clone();
        cloned.Freeze();

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action((() =>
        {
            Image = cloned;
        })));

        _g.Dispose();
    }
```

As you can see I am using a "special trick" to draw the graphics directly to a native WPF BitmapSource using GDI.

I am not sure this is the proper way of measuring but using this method I have managed to get some very decent results:

- More than 1 billion data points.
- Refresh rate of 5FPS.
- 10,000 new data points being pushed at 100hz.
- 10% CPU on an i7 Core laptop.
- The WPF UI and Rendering threads are completely free to do other operations.

I am the author of the open source library RealTimeGraphX (for WPF & UWP) that does exactly that.
https://github.com/royben/RealTimeGraphX

The rest of the graph components except the actual line series, are made using standard WPF controls and shapes, so they can be customized and manipulated easily.

Comment: Hi! I have successfully implemented your library, and it's far most powerful than LiveCharts! I Just can't add the zooming and panning! how to do that?

Comment: Just press the left Ctrl key while dragging the mouse.

Answer (score 4):

> Disclosure: I own ABT Software and have developed [SciChart](http://www.scichart.com), plus have contributed towards the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com) open source library

Unfortunately you're not missing anything. The retained mode rendering engine in WPF / Silverlight delivers poor performance for this type of work. I've worked on a number of systems that were upgraded from Windows Forms to WPF where the client was sorely dissapointed by the rendering performance of this "GPU Accelerated" framework!

Anyway, there is a way. Use immediate mode rendering. Check out the WriteableBitmap or InteropBitmap classes. There is an excellent open source library out there called [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com) by [Rene Schulte](http://kodierer.blogspot.com/) which I have contributed towards. WriteableBitmapEx provides some low-level drawing functions (GDI style) for drawing directly to bitmap. This delivers fantastic performance and low memory footprint (yes MS's fancy framework is beaten by a couple of well optimised for-loops and pointer to byte array).

If it is a specific third party chart component you're looking for, try [SciChart](http://www.scichart.com). SciChart is a component I have developed myself which seeks to fill the gap for ultra high performance WPF or Silverlight scientific / stock charts. It uses proprietary resampling algorithms to reduce the dataset before drawing, immediate mode rendering and a host of other optimisations such as object pooling and resource re-use, resulting in smooth refresh rates for very large datasets and low memory footprint.

Click on the performance demo on the link above (requires Silverlight 4). Currently SciChart is able to render 1,000,000 datapoints at around 5FPS (depending on target hardware), equivalent to 5,000,000 datapoints per second. A commercial license will be available in Q1 2012.

Comment: @DrABT - out of curiosity, does WritableBitmapEx support arbitrary anti-aliased like thickness or did you have to implement that separately in the SciChart component?

Comment: Hi Miky, WBEX doesn't support this as far as I'm aware. We've implemented it ourselves with a few different algorithms to get a good trade-off between quality and speed. One simple algorithm is discussed on the WBEX forums where you pre-cache an ellipse of size N and blit it at every point in a bresenham line. Surprisingly this works but will lead to jagged edges as WBEX has integer coordinates. To get a truly smooth wide line you need floating point - also expensive in terms of CPU! The SciChart High Quality renderer does this as does an experimental D3D renderer.

Comment: @DrABT thanks for the quick response. I'm not actively working on this at this time but perhaps I'll revisit our implementation at some point.

Answer (score 3):

Best results can be achieved by low-level DirectX programming, and utilizing HLSL shaders. System.Windows.Media namespace based rendering should be forgot instantly when max performance and real-time needs are important.

We were able to develop routines that can plot over 1000 million data points, e.g. 8 data feeds x 125 M data points, using wide line, no downsampling. The routines are part of [LightningChart](http://arction.com/products_lc_ultimate_sdk), WPF charts (and WinForms chart). It took like 7 years for us to get to this point... We made a [billion points example](http://arction.com/billion_data_points_visualization), with VS project and Youtube video included.

[I'm tech lead of LightningChart]

Comment: Hi Pasi - thanks for your answer; is LightningChart open source?  if not, would you mind sharing some more details about what type of low level DirectX primitives and shaders you're using?  are you using Direct2D or Direct3D? And what are you using the shaders for?

Comment: Hi Mike, LightningChart is not open source. We are using Direct3D also for 2D graphics. Direct2D is somehat slow and limited. Apologies I can't share all details here in public. Our performance is result of years of work, experimenting with different approaches and actual needs by customers.

Comment: I can't find any pricing on your website, how much does it cost? Looks pretty sweet. One comment though, please use a proper capture device instead of filming a monitor, that demo looks horrible!

Comment: Hi Chris, the pricing is visible in www.arction.com/pricing. For students, it's free. Thanks for your feedback on the video. We will make a better one.

Answer (score 2):

The retained mode rendering of WPF makes drawing/redrawing custom charts and images tricky to make performant, especially when those drawings contain a lot of objects.

The fastest drawing I've been able to do in WPF is by using a WritableBitmap and filling it with a call to WritePixels, which may be an option for you.  It vastly exceeded the drawing speed of the chart I wrote using PathGeometries and drawing to a Canvas.

I'm interested to see if there is a quicker middle ground.

Comment: One possible 'middle ground' would be to draw it onto a RenderContext in an OnRender override.  If nothing else this gives an enormous sense of mental relief as it feels much more like trad GDI/WinForms painting...   (More seriously, it should give access to decent rendering primitives without the overhead of building the retained-mode tree that is so often merely a redundant repetition of ones own object-graph)

Comment: I'm afraid OnRender still uses retained mode pipeline. All you're doing is posting retained mode objects to the graphics pipeline using this. To test it, put a breakpoint inside and minimise / maximise your window. If this was an immediate mode method (e.g. OnPaint in Winforms), You would force a redraw. I'm not 100% sure but I think resizing also won't cause OnRender to fire unless you expicitly set this as a flag.